# Can't Install Windows 7 on a second disk along side Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu, multi-boot

When trying to install Windows 7 after install Ubuntu, I get to the screen where I can see all the disks.

After clicking my second empty disk, formatting it from Windows, when I click next Windows returns:

```
Setup was unable to create a new system partition
```

How does one proceed installing Windows 7 in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 is a Prima Donna and refuses to get on the stage if Linux is there. The simplest solution is to open up the computer and unplug the disk with Linux. After this, windows has no issues installing. You can then reconnect the disk with Linux after the install (when the machine is powered down of course).